# Problems using timer2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, timer, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble using timer2 on the Raspberry Pi

Here's the code

```
************************************************************** 
#  tmr2_tst_04.py
#  https://github.com/ask/timer2
#  http://pymotw.com/2/threading/index.html#thread-objects
# ISSUES:
#
#   *)  Seems to respond only to even seconds
#
#   *)  Is off by 1 second.  i.e.  4000 gives a 5 second interrupt

import timer2
import time       #  for sleep
import signal,sys

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
    timer.stop()
    sys.exit(0)

#time_to_wait = 4500
#time_to_wait = 4999
time_to_wait = 4000.0    #  gives 5-second cycle time !!!
#time_to_wait = 500.0     #  doesn't work

tm = 0
tdiff = 0
tm_old = -1
iter = 0
to_print = False

def hello():
    global iter
    global tm, tdiff
    global tm_old
    global to_print

    tm = time.time()
    tdiff = (tm - tm_old) if tm_old > 0  else  0
    tm_old = tm
    iter += 1


#   buf = "%3d %d %f %6.4f %s" % (iter, time_to_wait, tm, tdiff, "Hello world")
#   print buf
    to_print = True

#    Set up to catch ^C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print 'Press Ctrl+C to exit'

#   Set up timer interrupt routine
timer = timer2.Timer()
timer.apply_interval(time_to_wait, hello)



#  Main program loop
while iter <= 10000:
    if to_print:
        buf = "%3d %d %f %6.4f %s" % (iter, time_to_wait, tm, tdiff, "Hello world")
        print buf
        to_print = False
    time.sleep((time_to_wait/1000)/2)

timer.stop()

*************************************************************************
```

This runs the thread "hello" every 5000 msec on the Raspberry Pi, but every 4000 msec on an UBUNTU machine

Second issue  -  if I try for a short time interval, say

```
time_to_wait = 500
```

it doesn't work at all -  just zips through the code with time differences of .1 msec!

Comment: Can you expand on "it doesn't work at all"?

Answer (score 0):

It's calling Python's sleep function, which takes an arguments in seconds. Ideally, what you have done would convert that to .25 seconds, but all of the numbers involved are integers.

As integers, 500/1000 = 0, 0/2 = 0, and so on. So, it waits the requested 0 seconds before proceeding. Change 1000 to 1000.0, for example, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks!

So, as I understand your answer, the timer2 function works only for integer seconds - is that correct?  I wonder why the time is then given in milliseconds ......


Still, there is the issue of a 5 second delay on the Pi and a 4 second delay on UBUNTU for a "time-to-wait" value of 4000.

Comment: Thanks! So, as I understand your answer, the timer2 function works only for integer seconds - is that correct? I wonder why the time is then given in milliseconds ...... Still, there is the issue of a 5 second delay on the Pi and a 4 second delay on UBUNTU for a "time-to-wait" value of 4000.

Comment: Thanks! So, as I understand your answer, the timer2 function works only for integer seconds - is that correct? I wonder why the time is then given in milliseconds ...... Still, there is the issue of a 5 second delay on the Pi and a 4 second delay on UBUNTU for a "time-to-wait" value of 4000.

Comment: I've looked but haven't been able to find in the documentation for timer2 where it says it is good to only integer seconds - could you point me to the proper documentation pages?

Comment: I'm not saying that about timer2 at all, I'm saying it about what you've input. You've input integers, so it will do integer division, and so you get 0 as the answer (try it in python shell, you'll see). If you make them floats, it won't happen, and you have a chance at the behavior you want.

Comment: If you look at my code, the 4000.0 is a floating point number, as is the (commented out) 500.0.  Am I missing something?

Comment: It is really more in answer to the follow-on question at the end. As for the 5000 vs 4000 issue, I admit, I'm not sure.